# Replacing the value of dynamic array inside a Solidity Struct

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have a dynamic array inside the UserListing and have problems accessing the dynamic array Listing[] to change the status to Cancelled in solidity programming. **The current push function is just appending another array to the list**, may I ask can we delete the previous listing and replace it with the new one /  change the value inside the dynamic array inside the Listing[]. Thank you so much if any help is provided :)

```
struct UserListing {
    address ownerAddress;
    Listing[] list;
}

struct Listing {
    uint listingId;
    ListingStatus status;
    address seller;
    address token;
    uint tokenId;
    uint price;
}

uint private _listingId = 0;

mapping(uint => Listing) private _listings;
mapping(address => UserListing) public userListings;

function cancel(uint listingId) public {
    Listing storage listing = _listings[listingId];

    require(msg.sender == listing.seller, "Only seller can cancel listing");
    require(listing.status == ListingStatus.Active, "Listing is not active");

    
    listing.status = ListingStatus.Cancelled;

    userListings[msg.sender].list.push(
        Listing({
            listingId : _listingId,
            status: ListingStatus.Cancelled,
            seller : msg.sender,
            token: listing.token,
            tokenId : listing.tokenId,
            price : listing.price
        })
    );

    IntERC721(listing.token).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, listing.tokenId);

    emit Cancel(listingId, listing.seller);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, inside `cancel` you want to find the item (a Listing) inside a user's list with given `listingId` and change its status. For this, you do not need to delete anything. You just iterate over the user's list. find the `Listing` and change its status.

```
 // i will modify userItems
 // since state variables are storage by default, modifying this will modify the state of the contract
 Listing[] storage userItems = userListings[msg.sender]
```

Now run a for loop:

```
for(uint256 i=0; i<userItems.length; i++){

   if userItems[i].listingId==listingId{
      userItems[i].status=ListingStatus.Cancelled,
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ;), apparently Listing[] storage userItems = userListings[msg.sender].list will work on this .